# Autoincrement UDF works in hive but returns null in Impala

Tags: java, impala, udf

I created a java function that creates auto incremental value, I also created a hive UDF based on this function, it works great in hive. I created an Impala UDF based on this function and it returns 'null' instead of auto incremental integer.

Here is the java UDF code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFType;

@UDFType(stateful = true)
public class AutoIncrementUDF extends UDF {

    int ctr;

    public int evaluate() {
        ctr++;
        return ctr;
    }
}
```

Creating Hive UDF:

```
create function autoincr as 'AutoIncrementUDF';
```

Creating Impala UDF:

```
create function autoincr() returns int LOCATION '/user/acombs/AutoIncrementUDF.jar' symbol='AutoIncrementUDF';
```

Using it in Hive and Impala:

```
select  autoincr() as testkey, * from mapfund
```

Any help is very appreciated!
Thank you ,
Anna

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Impala does not support the `@UDFType` annotation or the a notion of a stateful Hive UDF. We will add a note in our documentation to make this limitation known.

However, if you're trying to return the row number, you can use analytic window functions like `ROW_NUMBER()`.

For example,

```
> select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by int_col) as testkey, int_col, float_col from alltypestiny;
+---------+---------+-------------------+
| testkey | int_col | float_col         |
+---------+---------+-------------------+
| 1       | 0       | 0                 |
| 2       | 0       | 0                 |
| 3       | 0       | 0                 |
| 4       | 0       | 0                 |
| 5       | 1       | 1.100000023841858 |
| 6       | 1       | 1.100000023841858 |
| 7       | 1       | 1.100000023841858 |
| 8       | 1       | 1.100000023841858 |
+---------+---------+-------------------+
Fetched 8 row(s) in 0.12s
```

See [Impala Analytic Functions](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/latest/topics/impala_analytic_functions.html) for more details.